# Fragment is not scrolling inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-cardview

I am using `ViewPager` to show 4 different fragments.

The component tree of my activity:

```
     |_FrameLayout
        |_ LinearLayout (Vertical)
            Toolbar
            ViewPager
            TabLayout 
            RelativeLayout
```

And this is the component tree of my first fragment:

```
     ScrollView
         |_LinearLayout(Vertical)
             LinearLayout(Horizontal)             
             |_LinearLayout(Horizontal) 
                 |_CardView
                     TextView
             LinearLayout(Horizontal) 
             LinearLayout(Horizontal)
```

But the `Fragment` inside the `Viewpager` is not scrolling when the device is in portrait mode. When in landscape mode, it scrolls a bit (so the scroll is working) but views inside the `cardview` are shrinked. Is `CardView` is responsible for all this (As it is scroll-able)? How to fix this ? Please help.

Comment: please post some code

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your ScrollView with a [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) that helps you with nested scrolling

Comment: I've tried with `NestedScrollView` but it's still not working. Can you give me a working example please?

Comment: override onTouchListener of ViewPager

Comment: Try by adding `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` inside your viewpager xml

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. I found the cause. I used `layout_weight` inside the `scrollView`. After I used fixed height it is scrolling perfectly. I always use `layout_weight` (afaik, it makes ui more responsive). Now why does it cause mishap when I implement weights inside a `scrollView` ?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap both the viewpager.xml and fragment.xml in the scroll view like below:

viewpager.xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <!-- Along with other widgets -->

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Top App Bar  -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <!-- Top Action Bar  -->
                <include layout="@layout/action_bar" />

                <!-- Top Tabs  -->
                <include layout="@layout/top_tabs" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Middle Section (Body) -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout2">

            <include layout="@layout/viewpager" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Bottom Navigation View -->
        <include layout="@layout/bottom_navigation_view" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```